# Markov Chain Definition Question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, markov-process

This is a very basic question about Markov chains, but I am desperately lost.  We are given the following definition of a Markov chain:

$P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_n=x_n) = P(X_{n+1} \in A |X_n = x_n)$

for all measurable sets $A$.

Show that $P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k}) = P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})$ for all $k \ge 1$.

I started by trying to condition on $X_n$ and proceed from there (assuming the $X_i$ all have densities $f$), but I've gotten nowhere:

$$P(X_{n+1}\in A | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})$$

$$ = \int P(X_{n+1}\in A, X_n = x_n | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})f(x_n)dx_n$$

$$ = \int P(X_{n+1}\in A| X_n = x_n, X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})P(X_n = x_n| X_1 = x_1, ..., X_{n-k}=x_{n-k})f(x_n)dx_n$$

Comment: Use the law of iterated expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I've abused some of the notation because lines were getting to long:
$$\begin{align}P(X_{n+1} | X_1...X_{n-k})&=\int P(X_{n+1},X_n...X_{n-k+1}|X_1...X_{n-k})\overbrace{d\mathbf{x}}^{dx_n...dx_{n-k+1}}\\&=\int P(X_{n+1},X_n...X_{n-k+1}|X_{n-k})d\mathbf{x}\\&=P(X_{n+1}|X_{n-k})\end{align}$$

What we need to show is the transition from second to third line, which basically says:
$$P(X_{n}...X_{m+1}|X_1...X_m)=P(X_n...X_{m+1}|X_m)$$

which is intuitionally obvious but a needs a bit more clarification: 
$$\begin{align}P(X_{n}...X_{m+1}|X_1...X_m)&=\frac{P(X_{n}...X_1)}{P(X_m...X_1)}=\frac{P(X_n|X_{n-1})...P(X_{m+1}|X_m)P(X_m...X_1)}{P(X_m...X_1)}\\&=P(X_n|X_{n-1})...P(X_{m+1}|X_m)=Q\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}P(X_n...X_{m+1}|X_m)&=\frac{P(X_n...X_m)}{P(X_m)}=\frac{\int P(X_n...X_1)d\mathbf{x_{m-1...1}}}{P(X_m)}\\&=\frac{\int P(X_n|X_{n-1})...P(X_{m+1}|X_m)P(X_m...X_1)d\mathbf{x_{m-1...1}}}{P(X_m)}\\&=\frac{P(X_n|X_{n-1})...P(X_{m+1}|X_m)\overbrace{\int P(X_m...X_1)d\mathbf{x_{m-1...1}}}^{P(X_m)}}{P(X_m)}=Q\end{align}$$
which means our assumption is correct.